# Running VBA Macro in Open Office Calc

Tags: excel, vba, openoffice.org, basic, openoffice-calc

When I try to run the below macro I get an error 91, index out of bounds exception. I should note that this macro runs perfect in Excel, but I have to use openoffice calc for this file

https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html

I am not sure what to do to resolve this. The highlighted row when an error is thrown is the line beginning with "Set Rng"

```
Option VBASupport 1
    Sub html()

        Dim Sh As Worksheet
        Dim Rng As Range
        Dim Cell As Range
        Set Sh = Worksheets("new test")
        With Sh
            Set Rng = .Range("O2:O" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlup).Row)
        End With
        For Each Cell In Rng
            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Cell.Value
        Next Cell
    End Sub
```

Comment: I use Excel, but not touched OpenOffice in years.  I was often frustrated as the BASIC it uses is often much different. I'm surprised you got the `Set Rng =` honestly.  [this may help you out](https://www.openoffice.org/documentation/HOW_TO/various_topics/VbaStarBasicXref.pdf)

Comment: Don't try to run VBA macros in LibreOffice. Instead, write the code in LO Basic. The standard reference is http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php, but searching a particular topic online will often bring up code for that task. If you do want help for LO macros, you'll need to explain what you want the code to do, because most of us who know LO Basic do not read VBA very well. (I did work on a VBA project 15 years ago.)